# Configuring Development Environments

Tags: ide, vagrant, development-environment, devops

If the development environment is run on the host, is there a fast way to configure these and deploy them to multiple machines? If so, how?

Vagrant does this but as virtual machines, which may be painfully slow.

What are some viable alternatives?

Comment: Kinda confused by your question.  Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, if you are talking about using a resource pool to deploy and configure your VMs (dev VMs).

For the sake of simplicity, I assume your virtual environment is hosted on VMWare.

Here are a few things to start off with

- For Automating creation of VMs (deploying from templates, configure networking etc) you can use VMWare's PowerCLI (Powershell cmdlets) - more on this [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/index.html)
- If your dev environment is purely Windows then, for configuration management, you can use DSC (free) or if you (your org) can afford go the expensive route of using [SCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager)
- If you have a lot of Linux boxes to configure then, fortunately, you have more than one option - [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/configuration-management), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/), [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) or [SaltStack](http://saltstack.com/)

Spinning off and configuring these machines on demand entirely depends on your needs. One of the (more common ways) to do is, create a VM template (aka base vm) and then deploy a VM from this template.

This base template is usually a bare-bones OS + some common utils + tools - Once a VM is deployed from the template, you can then use one of the above mentioned CM (Configuration Management) tools to install/configure this VM.

Hope this gives some pointers in the right direction